# Getting error when trying to build ArcObjects project in VS 2015

Tags: plugins, visual-studio-2015, build, arcobjects

The install works correctly, you can create an Add-in project, but trying to build the project receives this error:

> The "ValidateAddInXMLTask" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>      at ESRI.ArcGIS.AddIns.SDK.MSBuild.ValidateAddInXMLTask.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find out Esri's solution for this error from bellow link which explains following points:
[EsriSupport link](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000012659)

ArcGIS Desktop and Engine add-ins have a dependency on the Microsoft Visual Studio Shell 12.0 library.

This error occurs when using Visual Studio 2015 without this library.

> Note:
>   If Visual Studio 2013 and 2015 are both installed on the machine, this problem does not occur. Visual Studio 2013 includes the Microsoft Visual Studio Shell 12.0 library.

The solution on Esri's support site says:

To resolve this issue, download and install the [Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Shell (Isolated) Redistributable Package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40777).

However, this download is no longer available.

But, don't worry I have uploaded this file on the drive, below is the link to download:

[My Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6VQpgl5K_cMRVVQcUtmWEJMdXM)